# Aurelia template parse error when string contains HTML entity for quote character

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

When I try to feed a string to Aurelia from a template and the string contains HTML entities representing the same quoting character as those surrounding the string, I get parser errors. Apparently the HTML enitities are interpreted before they reach Aurelia, but I'm not sure shy.

For example:

```html
${"Why wouldn&#39;t &quot;this&quot; work?"}
```

Results in

```
Error: Parser Error: Unconsumed token this at column 15 in expression ["Why wouldn't "this" work?"]
```

Could somebody tell me why entities are interpreted rather than just outputted to the DOM? And what can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems aurelia parser interprets &quot like equivalent to ".
This makes your expression look incorrect to the parser.
You should escape the " quotes like this:

```
${"Why wouldn&#39;t \"this\" work?"}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but do you also know why the parser does this? It seems incorrect to me.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I forgot that the template is added to the DOM (and interpreted by the browser) before Aurelia ever gets to it. That explains it.